# Stream data from client to server component

Tags: typescript, next.js13

I receive data chunk by chunk from an external API. I succeed to read that data chunk by chunk in my server component but I fail to send each chunk to my client component:

**/app/api/test/route.tsx**

```
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
    const data = await req.json()

    let answer = ""


    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.API}/test/55aaf0fd-287b-4317-81e8-0e0fc1b1cc20`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    const textDecoder = new TextDecoder();

    if (response.body != null) {
      const reader = response.body.pipeThrough(new TransformStream()).getReader()
      while (true) {
        const {value, done} = await reader.read();
        if (done) return NextResponse.json(answer);
        const decodedString = textDecoder.decode(value);
        answer += decodedString
      }}
```

I tried multiple approach, that one is the last one. One the example above, decodedString represent my chunks and answer all the chunks gathered.

**My component**

```
const ret = await fetch(`/api/test/${id}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            }).then(response => {
                console.log("then");
                
                if (response.body != null) {
                    const reader = response.body.getReader();
                    return new ReadableStream({
                        start(controller) {
                        function push() {
                            reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
                            if (done) {
                                controller.close();
                                return;
                            }
                            controller.enqueue(value);
                            push();
                            });
                        }
                        push();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).then(stream => {
                return new Response(stream).text();
            }).then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error('Fetch error:', err);
            });
```

On my console (server side) I have each chunk displayed one by one. On my client, I have only the final result

**Additional options I tried**:

- **SSE** method with **EventSource** but with NextJS13, I need to declare HTTP methods in my route. It trigger an error if I try to reach a custom named default function
- **Axios** with response.data.on to read each chunk but same issue, it work on server side, not on client side
- **Returning a Response** object with the transformStream but the call api never end even after the last chunk of data:

```
return new Response(responseStream.readable, {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8",
        Connection: "keep-alive",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-transform",
        "X-Accel-Buffering": "no",
        "Content-Encoding": "none",
      },
    });
```

I think this last option is interesting because here, I return transformStream().readable while in my first sample of code on my server component, I return only the full answer with NextResponse.json().